# Cordova App: Stop JavaScript from running when App is closed

Tags: javascript, ios, ipad, cordova

I have a big problem with my cordova (version 4.0) App in iOS:

It uses HTML5 Audio triggered with buzz.js. Now the problem is, that I want all audio to stop/mute when leaving the app. I expected this to be the standard behaviour, but this is not the case. When I leave the app in the iPad emulator, it keeps on playing the audio in the background.

Through my research I just found posts of people who had the exact opposite problem and wanted to keep playing audio with the app in the background.

I know I could try to handle this issue with the resume and pause events cordova provides, but since iOS doesn't allow volume control for HTML5 audio it will probably be difficult/lots of work.

As I said, I'm using Cordova 4 CLI to build my app using xCode 6.1

I have no knowledge of Objective-C etc, just JavaScript.

The plugins installed with the project are the following:

```
me.apla.cordova.app-preferences 0.4.2 "AppPreferences"
org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser 0.5.3 "InAppBrowser"
org.apache.cordova.statusbar 0.1.8 "StatusBar"
```

Answer (score 0):

The `pause` and `resume` events should do what you want. Have you tried using them? For example:

```
document.addEventListener("pause", function() {
    myBuzzSound.fadeOut();
});
```

and on resume...

```
document.addEventListener("resume", function() {
    myBuzzSound.fadeIn();
});
```

Comment: That's what I wanted to explain, that I can't really use these functions since iOS doesn't support fading or muting. Also there are many sounds played at different times and it will be hard work to detect which ones should resume to play on "resume"-Event. I was more wondering if there is any easy configuration or something (for example to add in info.plist). Because I believe it's also the standard behaviour of the Safari App, that when it's closed, video and sound is stopped.